# Generators seems to skip a step when sending data

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am trying to understand why the below is happening.

Let us assume that we have this simple `is_even` function:

```py
    def is_even(num):
        return num % 2 == 0
```

And then we also have this generator function:

```py
    def get_evens():
        start_value = 0
        while True:
            if is_even(start_value):
                incoming = yield start_value
                if incoming is not None:
                    start_value = incoming
            start_value += 1
```

The above should simple yield to us the next available even number.

So if we do something like this:

```py
    evens_gen = get_evens()
    print(next(evens_gen))
    print(next(evens_gen))
    print(next(evens_gen))
    print(next(evens_gen))
```

The output would be:

```
0
2
4
6
```

Now assume that we want to send some data to the generator in order to move to specific number check. e.g:

```py
    evens_gen.send(500)
```

And then we attempt to call `next` again

```py
    print(next(evens_gen))
```

The output would be

```
504
```

What I noticed while debugging is that the value of `incoming` is still set as 500 when the loop is reaching the check for 502. Then it turns to None.

Still I cannot grasp why this is happening. Should not the first `next` post `send` be 502 ?

Edit: Forgot to mention that this is checked with 3.8 and 3.10 versions

Comment: Could you update your question to show exactly what behavior you're asking about? When I test your code, `evens_gen.send(500)` returns `502`, and then `next(evens_gen)` returns `504`, which all seems to be working as expected.

Comment: The part you're missing is that `evens_gen.send(500)` returns the value 502.  The generating function gets the value, and immediately returns the next item in the sequence.

Comment: @FrankYellin I think you just solved it!

Comment: Thank you @FrankYellin. I got it with this. I indeed missed this part exactly. 

@larsks, The expected behavior me would be that the first `next` call post send, to return 502. I assume you did something `x = evens_gen(500)` to get 502.

Comment: I copied your code above, but looked at the value returned from the one place you didn't include a print statement.